# Repeating-linear-gradient bug with AWS amplify

Tags: css, aws-amplify

I develop a web-site deployed with AWS Amplify. I've created a "X" button using following CSS:

```
  background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0% 43%, #10387d 43%  57%),
  repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 0% 43%, #10387d 43%  57%);
```

When I run it with npm everything is OK.
But when I open it at my domain, my button looks like a circle, not an "X".
The reason for it is the background property, in this case it looks like this:

```
background:
repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,#0000 43%,#10387d 43% 57%),
repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,#0000 43%,#10387d 43% 57%)
```

As you see transparent now is #0000 (that's alright) and 0% is missing after transparent, when I manually add 0% to CSS it looks as it should "X".
I know the problem^ it is a missing 0% in CSS after my CSS code is compiled with AWS Amplify, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you try replacing `transparent` with `rgba(0,0,0,0)`?

Comment: @shadow-lad I did and result is the same, in browser it turns into #0000, but I don't care about transparent, the problem is that 0% after it is omitted, that's why I see a circle instead of a cross. This only happen when I access my web site with its domain, at localhost it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write CSS in another way:

```
  background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 0% 43%, $mainTextColor 43%  57%, transparent 57% 100%),
  repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 0% 43%, $mainTextColor 43%  57%, transparent 57% 100%);
```

Now it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't effect the design too much, just change the 0% to 1% (or 0.1%, 0.2%...) in your CSS and it should display properly

```
 background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 1% 43%, #10387d 43%  57%),
  repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 1% 43%, #10387d 43%  57%);
```